# What to put at CALLBACK_URL in twitter using Oauth from my android application?

Tags: android, url, twitter, callback, oauth

I am developing an application of Twitter -Client. i got lots of hint form this site. i write some come that is

```
import oauth.signpost.OAuthProvider;
import oauth.signpost.basic.DefaultOAuthProvider;
import oauth.signpost.commonshttp.CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer;
import twitter4j.Status;
import twitter4j.Twitter;
import twitter4j.TwitterFactory;
import twitter4j.http.AccessToken;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class TwitterConnetcion extends Activity {

     private static final String APP ="OAUTH";

     private Twitter twitter;

     private OAuthProvider provider;

     private CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer consumer;


     private String CONSUMER_KEY ="MyConsumerKey";

     private String CONSUMER_SECRET ="MyConsumersecrete";
     private String CALLBACK_URL ="SoftDroidbyDhrumil://twitterconnetcion";///SoftDroid is my twitter //Apllication that i registered in Twitter site
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        try {
            consumer = new CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET);
            provider = new DefaultOAuthProvider("https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token","https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token","https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize");

            String authUrl = provider.retrieveRequestToken(consumer, CALLBACK_URL);
            Log.i("Dhrumil",authUrl);
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please authorize this app!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            this.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(authUrl)));
            Log.i("Dhrumil","Browser Start"); } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.i("Dhrumil"+APP, e.toString());
            Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onNewIntent(intent);

        Uri uri = intent.getData();
        if (uri != null && uri.toString().startsWith(CALLBACK_URL)) {

                String verifier = uri.getQueryParameter(oauth.signpost.OAuth.OAUTH_VERIFIER);

                Log.i("Dhrumil verifier",verifier);
                try {
                        // this will populate token and token_secret in consumer
                        provider.retrieveAccessToken(consumer, verifier);

                        // TODO: you might want to store token and token_secret in you app settings!!!!!!!!
                        AccessToken a = new AccessToken(consumer.getToken(), consumer.getTokenSecret());
                        Log.i("Dhrumil AccessToken",a.toString());
                        // initialize Twitter4J
                        twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
                        twitter.setOAuthConsumer(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET);
                        twitter.setOAuthAccessToken(a);

                        // create a tweet
                        Date d = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
                        String tweet = "#OAuth working! " + d.toLocaleString();

                        // send the tweet
                        twitter.updateStatus(tweet);

                        // feedback for the user...

                        Toast.makeText(this, tweet, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.e(APP, e.getMessage());
                        Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }



    }
    }}
```

I compile fine and run this application it will redirect me at Twitter site for "Allow" permission. Then I want to come back to my android application but i got error" could not found "SoftDroidbyDhrumil://twitterconnetcion?OuathToken=somoething"

What do I write at my CallBack URL so i can come back from android browser to my application?

Answer (score 4):

You need an Intent Filter to a specific URL that your app will handle on access.

So you will redirect to something like:

yourcustomscheme://witterconnetcion?OuathToken=somoething

In the middle of the following page, it's described 
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html